# Getting text value of a HTML tag through Selenium Web Automation in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, praw

I am making a reddit bot that will look for certain attributes in comments, use selenium to visit the information website, and use `driver.find_element_by...` to get the value inside that tag, but it is not working.

When I use `driver.find_element_by_class_name()`, this is the data returned:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f454dcf92728b9db4de080a27a844bf7", element="514bd57d-99d7-4fce-a05d-3fa92f66ad49")>
```

when I use `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".style-scope.ytd-video-renderer")`, this is returned:

```
[
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="43cb953cde81df270260bf769fe081a2", element="6b4ee3e2-5e6b-48e2-8ec8-9083bf15baea")>, 
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="43cb953cde81df270260bf769fe081a2", ...
]
```

when I use `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".style-scope.ytd-video-renderer")`.

Suppose that this is what I'm trying to locate (The above code returned the above Selenium data for this tag):

```
<yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-video-renderer" aria-label="Sword Art Online: Alicization Lycoris Opening Full『ReoNa - Scar/let』 by Melodic Star 2 months ago 4 minutes, 18 seconds 837,676 views">Sword Art Online: Alicization Lycoris Opening Full『ReoNa - Scar/let』</yt-formatted-string>
```

**What I want**

I want `Sword Art Online: Alicization Lycoris Opening Full『ReoNa - Scar/let』` returned.

What could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close enough. When you use `driver.find_element_by_class_name()` the first matching [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is returned. On printing the same, the output is:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="f454dcf92728b9db4de080a27a844bf7", element="514bd57d-99d7-4fce-a05d-3fa92f66ad49")>
```

which represents the *WebElement* itself,  which possibly contains the desired text.

On similar lines `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".style-scope.ytd-video-renderer")` returns a *list* of matching *WebElements* and on printing those, the output is:

```
[
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="43cb953cde81df270260bf769fe081a2", element="6b4ee3e2-5e6b-48e2-8ec8-9083bf15baea")>, 
  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="43cb953cde81df270260bf769fe081a2",
  ...
]
```

---

### Solution

To extract the text **Sword Art Online: Alicization Lycoris Opening Full『ReoNa - Scar/let』** from the following HTML:

```
<yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytd-video-renderer" aria-label="Sword Art Online: Alicization Lycoris Opening Full『ReoNa - Scar/let』 by Melodic Star 2 months ago 4 minutes, 18 seconds 837,676 views">Sword Art Online: Alicization Lycoris Opening Full『ReoNa - Scar/let』</yt-formatted-string>
```

You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-video-renderer").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-video-renderer']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally, to print the text **3,862.76** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-video-renderer"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-video-renderer']"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### Outro

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Thanks, just want you to dwell on that a bit more - suppose that I have multiple `<span class="tags"> Lorem Ipsum </>`, and I use the `driver.find_elements_by...` instead of the `driver.find_element_by...`, will it return the text as one long string or will it have a new line for each attribute (I'm storing this data and having it reply to a Reddit comment via PRAW, so if I use `comment.reply("tags: {}".format(tags))`, will it just put all the tags together in one string with no spaces or will it give a space between each tag?

Comment: @KazutoKiritoKirigaya `driver.find_elements` will always return a list. You have to iterate the list to extract the text.

Comment: That's the thing, it says that `driver.find_elements_by...` is not iterable.

Comment: @KazutoKiritoKirigaya True, but we can offer you an optimal solution too :) Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement. StackOverflow contributers will be happy to help you out.

Comment: Is there no obvious alternative solution to this problem so that I can extract the text from the `driver.find_elements_by...`?

Comment: @KazutoKiritoKirigaya There are solutions for that as well. But as the context is different so I'm suggesting you to raise a new question so this question and the new one both are helpful for the future readers.

Comment: Done, hope you answer there! Found your answer to this quite helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Use **`.text`**:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/h1/yt-formatted-string')
print(element.text)
```